# How to find matching value(dictionary) from an element(list), and printing corresponding match?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm not finding the matching (elements) of a list to all the dictionary (values). What's the syntax?

My goal is: whatever element in list, I want to find a matching in all values of the dictionary. If so, then print the corresponding dictionary (key, value) and print the list that matches it.

I specified `any(elem)` of the list to match `all(val)` values of the dictionary.

```
x = ['AL3G13280', 'AL3G13290']
y = {'Protein of unknown function (DUF784)': 'AL1006U10010', 'FK506- and rapamycin-binding protein 15 kD-2': 'AL3G13280', 'Werner syndrome-like exonuclease': 'AL7G42630'}

for elem in x:
  for key, val in y.items():
    if any(elem) == all(val):
      print(key, val),
      print(TandClustList)
```

I expect this to be printed:

```
('FK506- and rapamycin-binding protein 15 kD-2', 'AL3G13280') [['AL3G13280', 'AL3G13290']]
```

This was the ACTUAL print:

```
('Werner syndrome-like exonuclease', 'AL7G42630') [['AL3G13280', 'AL3G13290']]
('Protein of unknown function (DUF784)', 'AL1006U10010') [['AL3G13280', 'AL3G13290']]
('FK506- and rapamycin-binding protein 15 kD-2', 'AL3G13280') [['AL3G13280', 'AL3G13290']]
```

How can I reach the expected print result that I want?

Answer (score 1):

You're misunderstanding the purpose of `all()` and `any()`. I don't think they're required here, but a quick explanation:

- `all()` returns True if *all* elements in some iterable (e.g. a tuple, list, string, generator etc.) evaluate to True, and False otherwise.
- `any()` returns True if *any* element in some iterable evaluates to True, and False otherwise.

So if you call `all()` on a string, the result should always be True, because every "element" of the string is another string containing a single character (strings only evaluate to false if they are empty). In the special case where the string is empty, `all()` still returns True.

Similarly, if you call `any()` on a string, the result should always be True, except for the empty string, in which case it will return False.

In your example, you should get the output you desire by simply removing the calls to `all()` and `any()`, like so:

```py
for elem in x:
  for key, val in y.items():
    if elem == val:
      print(key, val),
      print(TandClustList)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `all()` or `any()` simply you can do with:

```
x = ['AL3G13280', 'AL3G13290']
y = {'Protein of unknown function (DUF784)': 'AL1006U10010', 'FK506- and rapamycin-binding protein 15 kD-2': 'AL3G13280', 'Werner syndrome-like exonuclease': 'AL7G42630'}

for key, val in y.items():
    if val in x:
        print(key,val)
        print(TandClustList)
```

**Using Dictionary Comprehension**

```
x = ['AL3G13280', 'AL3G13290']
y = {'Protein of unknown function (DUF784)': 'AL1006U10010', 'FK506- and rapamycin-binding protein 15 kD-2': 'AL3G13280', 'Werner syndrome-like exonuclease': 'AL7G42630'}

print({ key:val for(key, val) in y.items() if val in x})
print(TandClustList)
```

**Output:**

```
('FK506- and rapamycin-binding protein 15 kD-2', 'AL3G13280')
[['AL3G13280', 'AL3G13290']]
```